# Issues while doing retopology/low poly mesh hides high poly mesh

Tags: retopology

I am doing retopology on a model, and when I opened the file today the low poly mesh seems to hide the high poly mesh also with the backsides of the lowpoly faces.

In other words, the backside of the surrounding low poly mesh is displayed in front of the high poly mesh. I have checked the "in front"-option in object properties as I usually do, but normally its just the front sides of the surrounding mesh that hides the underlying high poly mesh. Please see video for clear example. What should I do to fix this?

https://youtu.be/0tuW4dEKE-0

Answer (score 0):

Backface culling! Solved it by checking the backface culling option in viewport shading box.

Comment: I'd like to know if your normals are correct. Culling backfaces can solve some issues but flipped normals on your highpoly mesh may result in some more issue later on

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see all the normals are pointing the right directions.